# Why should I have to specify a parent for the QFileDialog

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Why should I have to specify a parent for the `QFileDialog`?

```
const QString& file_name = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(
    0, // this
    "Export",
    QDir::currentPath(),
    "Excel files (*.xlsx)"
);
```

What's the point? Can I just set it to 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can set it to 0.
`QFileDialog` inherits `QDialog`. [From Qt 5 **QDialog** documentation:](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#QDialog)

> ...A dialog is always a top-level widget, **but if it has a parent, its
>   default location is centered on top of the parent**...

**update:** An important addition is in the first comment.

Comment: In addition to that, on windows, dialogs with a parent will not have their own taskbar entry, but share it with the parent.